# Find missing number from not sequence number

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have a database with 5 columns (`A1,A2,A3,A4,A5`) which store 5 numbers.

The 5 numbers are `"1,2,3,4,5"`.

```
A1     A2     A3     A4     A5
-------------------------------
2      4      5      Null  Null
```

I want get the missing number which is "1" and "3".
How do I find the missing number from 5 numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An elegant solution that is extensible beyond the 5 values presented in your question makes use of a [numbers table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable) (as shown in the link, a numbers table is invaluable for a multitude of tasks).

Here's the setup for the numbers table, which in this case is limited to 256 numbers since you're using a small range in the question.

```sql
/* 
    create a numbers table with numbers from 0 to 
    255 (the range of the tinyint data type).
*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [#numbers];
GO

CREATE TABLE [#numbers]
(
    [n] tinyint NOT NULL
);

WITH [numbers]
AS
(
    SELECT [v].[n]
    FROM
    (
        VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)
    ) [v]([n])
)
INSERT INTO [#numbers]
(
    [n]
)
SELECT TOP(255)
    [number] = 
                  ([n1].[n] * 100)
                + ([n2].[n] * 10) 
                + ([n3].[n] * 1)
FROM 
    [numbers] [n1]
    CROSS JOIN [numbers] [n2]
    CROSS JOIN [numbers] [n3]
ORDER BY
      ([n1].[n] * 100)
    + ([n2].[n] * 10) 
    + ([n3].[n] * 1);
```

Next, we'll create the table you mention in your question:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [#rows];
CREATE TABLE [#rows]
(
      [a1]  tinyint  NULL
    , [a2]  tinyint  NULL
    , [a3]  tinyint  NULL
    , [a4]  tinyint  NULL
    , [a5]  tinyint  NULL
);
```

Here, we populate the row with your values:

```sql
INSERT INTO [#rows] ([a1], [a2], [a3])
VALUES (2, 4, 5);
```

The contents of the `[#rows]` table:

| a1 | a2 | a3 | a4 | a5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 4 | 5 | NULL | NULL |

I'm going to use an [UNPIVOT clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#unpivot-unpivot_clause) to turn columns into rows.  For clarity, this is what the `UNPIVOT` looks like on its own:

```sql
SELECT 
    [upv].[value]
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM [#rows]
) [src]
UNPIVOT
(
    [value] FOR [column] IN ([a1], [a2], [a3], [a4], [a5])
) [upv]
ORDER BY
    [upv].[value];
```

The intermediate results of the `UNPIVOT` query:

| value |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

As you can see, we're missing the values `1` and `3`.  Here's where we display the missing values by combining the results of the `UNPIVOT` with an [EXCEPT T-SQL operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) against the `[#numbers]` table to show the missing values:

```sql
SELECT
    [missing_number] = [n].[n]
FROM
    [#numbers] [n]
WHERE 
    [n].[n]     > 0
    AND [n].[n] <= 5
EXCEPT
SELECT 
    [upv].[value]
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM [#rows]
) [src]
UNPIVOT
(
    [value] FOR [column] IN ([a1], [a2], [a3], [a4], [a5])
) [upv];
```

The `EXCEPT` operator shows distinct results from the left side of the operator that do not exist in the results from the right side of the operator.  The results are:

| missing_number |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 3 |

Comment: Thank for your answer,but is it possible just display the column with not null value? I only have single row of record. And I want to get the missing value only.

Comment: After get the record, I will insert the missing value into column A4 and column A5. Column A4 may store "1" or "3"  So which return format you recommend?

Answer (score 2):

```
Select Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(
Replace('12345',(Cast(Coalesce(A5,0) as varchar(1))),''),
(Cast(Coalesce(A4,0) as varchar(1))),''),
(Cast(Coalesce(A3,0) as varchar(1))),''),
(Cast(Coalesce(A2,0) as varchar(1))),''),
(Cast(Coalesce(A1,0) as varchar(1))),'') from Table1
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b717b/6)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```sql
WITH sequence AS
(
  SELECT 1 n UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1 FROM sequence WHERE n < 5
)
SELECT n
  FROM sequence s LEFT JOIN table1 t
    ON s.n IN (t.a1, t.a2, t.a3, t.a4, t.a5)
 WHERE t.a1 IS NULL
```

Output:

```
| N |
|---|
| 1 |
| 3 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd079/7)** demo

Comment: WHERE n < 6 I think, but I do like your solution

Comment: @JohnBingham Thanks. But it is exactly how it should be. You probably don't take into account the very first value `1` (or row if you wish) that is then union'ed with all others. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd079/8.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need a table of integers from 1 to (in this case) 5:

```
DECLARE @ints table (n int);
INSERT @ints VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);
```

second, we get the numbers in the table row into a single comparable set:

```
SELECT x INTO #all FROM (
    SELECT A1 as x FROM myTable WHERE ID = myRow
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A2 as x FROM myTable WHERE ID = myRow
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A3 as x FROM myTable WHERE ID = myRow
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A4 as x FROM myTable WHERE ID = myRow
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A5 as x FROM myTable WHERE ID = myRow
    ) y
```

then you can derive the answer:

```
SELECT @ints.n
FROM @ints left join #all on @ints.n = #all.x
WHERE #all.x is null
ORDER BY 1
```